# How to convert a list of numbers into an integer?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, int

I have a list like:
    list = [1, 2, 3]

I need to convert it to a triple digit like:
    "123"

Comment: Please search for existing duplicates before creating a question that you fully intend to self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
''.join(str(digit) for digit in lst) # '123'
```

Comment: Is my_integer an `int`?

Comment: nope its an str but its easy to convert them just like (   some_string(whom has a number in it) = int(some_string

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_integer = "".join(map(str, my_list))
print(my_integer)
```

it will give me :

> > > 12345

Comment: Is my_integer an `int`?

Comment: @Alex.S - No, so it doesn't really answer the question as described by the title, which is odd, because it's a self-answer.